# How to use global module after imported?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I've followed the example from the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration) on how to create a basic config service.

At the bottom of the tutorial it says you can opt to declare it globally:

"Instead of importing `ConfigModule` repeatingly in all your modules, you can also declare `ConfigModule` as a global module."

So following the documentation for global modules I have:

- Imported `Global` from `@nestjs/common` into `ConfigModule`.
- Added the `@Global()` decorator to `ConfigModule`.
- Imported `ConfigModule` into `AppModule`.
- Added `ConfigModule` to the `imports` array.

So what's next? I have tried to inject `ConfigService` into `AppService` however it doesn't resolve.

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { ConfigModule } from '../config/config.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule,
  ],
  controllers: [
    AppController,
  ],
  providers: [
    AppService,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  private readonly config: ConfigService;

  constructor(config: ConfigService) {
    this.config = config;
  }

  getHello(): string {
    return config.get('DB_NAME');
  }
}
```

**config.module.ts**:

```
import { Module, Global } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from './config.service';

@Global()
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ConfigService,
      useValue: new ConfigService(`${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`),
    },
  ],
  exports: [
    ConfigService,
  ],
})
export class ConfigModule {}
```

**config.service.ts**:

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import * as fs from 'fs';

export class ConfigService {
  private readonly envConfig: { [key: string]: string };

  constructor(filePath: string) {
    this.envConfig = dotenv.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath));
  }

  get(key: string): string {
    return this.envConfig[key];
  }
}
```

I expect to be able to inject `ConfigService` and access it from any module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `this` qualifier in your `AppService`:

```
getHello(): string {
  return this.config.get('DB_NAME');
         ^^^^^
}
```

Also, the import is missing:

```
import { ConfigService } from './config/config.service';
```

Comment: It says that you do not need to import (and register) the `ConfigModule` multiple times; just once in the `AppModule`. The `ConfigService` however, has to be imported everywhere it's used (injected).

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, thanks. The wording of the last bit had me confused. "Afterward, the CatsService provider will be ubiquitous, although CatsModule won't be imported." Only the provider is ubiquitous. Thanks.